# AngularJS getId with save from resources

Tags: scala, resources, angularjs, playframework-2.0

I'm new to AngularJS and my question is, When I save a Task with the resource it sends the information correctly to the database. The server when receives the POST responds with the ID of the Task created.

I have something like this

```
$scope.save = function(){     
        var retorno = Task.save($scope.task);
        console.log("Retorno = "+retorno);
        $scope.tasks.push($scope.task);
}
```

The retorno value in the console is Retorno = [object Object]

The id comes from here

```
def newTask = SecuredAction { implicit request =>
    println("TaskController.newTask")
    taskForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors =>
        BadRequest(views.html.tasks(request.user, Task.all(request.user.id.id), errors, errors)),
      _publicTask => {
        val id = Task.create(_publicTask.label,request.user.id.id, _publicTask.date)
        //Redirect(routes.TaskController.tasks())
        id match{
          case Some(_id) => Ok(_id.toString).as("application/json")
          case None => Ok("error")
          case _ => Ok("ERROR")
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

It returns something like this

516e750ee4b0230023ba5acc

So, how can I handle this return in the controller.
By the way, I want that because when I push the Task, it goes without ID, making it impossible to delete without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Angular docs on $resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) states that

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.

So instead of

```
var retorno = Task.save($scope.task);
$scope.tasks.push($scope.task);
```

you should do it callback way

```
var retorno = Task.save($scope.task, function() {
    // here retorno should already have ID in it
    // and you may want to set it to a task
    $scope.tasks.push($scope.task); 
});
```

Comment: var retorno = Task.save($scope.task, function(data){
        console.log("Retorno = "+retorno);
        console.log("DATA = "+data);
            $scope.task._id = retorno;
            $scope.tasks.push($scope.task);
        });
        console.log("Retorno = "+retorno);

both retorno and data give an [Object object]

Comment: Replace console.log("xx" + y) with console.log("xx", y) and see what you actually got from server (console.log accepts multiple params. console.log("xx", y, z, s, t) will work also).

Comment: Resource {0: "5", 1: "1", 2: "6", 3: "e", 4: "9", 5: "7", 6: "0", 7: "f", 8: "e", 9: "4", 10: "b", 11: "0", 12: "2", 13: "3", 14: "0", 15: "0", 16: "2", 17: "3", 18: "b", 19: "a", 20: "5", 21: "a", 22: "e", 23: "d", $get: function, $save: function, $query: function, $remove: function, $delete: function…}
0: "5"
1: "1"
2: "6"
3: "e"
4: "9"
5: "7"
6: "0"
7: "f"
8: "e"
9: "4"
10: "b"
11: "0"
12: "2"
13: "3"
14: "0"
15: "0"
16: "2"
17: "3"
18: "b"
19: "a"
20: "5"
21: "a"
22: "e"
23: "d"
__proto__: Resource

I got the correct id, but separated, probably in chars. How can i put them together?

Comment: i got to change the taskcontroller to output Ok(id.toString).as("application/json")
then in task to return 
val json = new JSONObject()
json.put("_id", newId.toString)
json

then in the controller i can use retorno._id or even data._id

so thanks for the answer!

Comment: Actually seems like there was a problem with type of _id. Applying toString to it didn't produce a string but an array. Because Ok("abcdef").as("application/json") in Play controller returns a string.

Comment: yeah, it's an ObjectID, so maybe that was the problem.

Comment: If it's MongoDB then there's .stringify method.